# Double.TryParse with a string having two decimal points

Tags: c#, double

This might be a simple and basic question, but, thought of confirming with you. Im in the process of writing code to validate the entered text information is double or not. In my code, below is the line to validate the speed value taken from a text box.

```
    double _mSpeed = 0.0;
    if (!Double.TryParse(txtboxSpeed.Text, out _mSpeed))
               throw new Exception("Input value for Speed is invalid !!!");
```

But, if user provides **4.4.4** in speed text box, TryParse is parsing the text string to **444.0** value. Im wondering this is correct or not. Please share your thoughts whether if user enters any value with 2 decimal points, should it not parse to double or what is the expected behavior.

Comment: What culture are you using?  What is its thousands separator?

Comment: That fails for me (`en-US`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In cultures where `.` is the decimal separator, like `en-US` and the invariant culture, `4.4.4` is not valid. In other cultures, like `de-DE`, `,` is the decimal separator and `.` is the thousands separator, so `4.4.4` is `444` (with nonstandard, but acceptable, thousands separators inserted, like `4,4,4` in the `en-US` culture).

```
double.Parse("4.4.4", new CultureInfo("de-DE")) // 444
double.Parse("4.4.4", new CultureInfo("en-US")) // FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
double.Parse("4,4,4", new CultureInfo("en-US")) // 444
double.Parse("4,4,4", new CultureInfo("de-DE")) // FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: thank you very much for the information. Now, I could resolve the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be that the Culture currently used by your application treats comma as decimal separator instead of period. You can force it to use period as decimal separator by setting culture to en-GB.

```
double _mSpeed = 0.0;
if (!Double.TryParse(txtboxSpeed.Text,NumberStyles.Any,CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"), out _mSpeed))
           throw new Exception("Input value for Speed is invalid !!!");
```

Comment: thank you very much for the information. Now, I could resolve the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a `CultureInfo` for a specific culture that uses your number format (e.g., "en-US"), you can also just specify `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`.

```
 double val1, val2;     
 bool b1 = double.TryParse("4.4.4", NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out val1);
 bool b2 = double.TryParse("4,444.4", NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out val2);
```

In the above code `b1` is set to `false` but `b2` succeeds and `val2` is `4444.4`.